# Column reference in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between referencing a column by by just name of the column and using "$" sign infront like shown below.

df.select("name").show() and df.select($"name").show()

I read on the following page that it actually creates free column reference with no association to dataset.

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Column.html

what does "$" signify in this case? What does it do internally ? I tried getting info from spark page but it does not provide much info.

Any help to understand this is appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the page you provided, the dollar sign converts a column name into a Column object with the help of the class `SQLContext.implicits$`.

When using it inside a select method for an existing column in the dataframe (without constructing expressions), both `df.select($"name")` and `df.select("name")` are equivalent as the select method is overloaded for both cases.